# Replace Key And Values with actual Data from the List

Tags: c#

I Have the following method in C# which takes in a list of columns and list of rows and adds into a dynamic list:

```
public static List < dynamic > RecordFactoryNew(IEnumerable < Property > columns, DataRowCollection dr) {

    dynamic output = new List < dynamic > ();
    dynamic cust = new ExpandoObject();

    for (int i = 0; i < dr.Count; i++) {
        List < dynamic > list = new List < dynamic > ();

        foreach(var col in columns) {
            SetDateTimeKindUtc(columns, dr[i][col.Name]);
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, dynamic > (col.Name, ((IDictionary < string, dynamic > ) cust)[col.Name] = dr[i][col.Name]));
        }

        output.Add(list);
    }

    return output;
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ Key: 'Links', Value: 'Test.com' },
{ Key: 'ReportID', Value: 21 },
{ Key: 'Verified', Value: true } etc....
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{ Links: 'Test.com', ReportID': 21, Verified: true etc.... },
```

My return type **must remain a List dynamic** as the column names are not a fixed set and type.

How would I go about achieving the expected output?

Comment: can't you use https://www.newtonsoft.com/json to serialize it?

Comment: no, i just need my code inside the method to be changed

Comment: I know you said already `dynamic`, but what do you want the return type to be at runtime?  Perhaps `List<List<ExpandoObject>>` ?  I suspect if you try writing this code again without using the dynamic keyword you would get your answer.

Comment: Nope, it needs to remain List<dynamic>

Comment: No, but dynamic isn't a type.  It is just a keyword that means you are not telling us the type.  Much the same as `var` is not type. What type do you want?

Comment: Oh right, anything that achieves the expected output tbh

Comment: Does this work?             dynamic output = new List<dynamic>();

            for (int i = 0; i < dr.Count; i++)
            {
                dynamic cust = new ExpandoObject();

                foreach (var col in columns)
                {
                    cust[col.Name] = dr[i][col.Name];
                }

                output.Add(cust);
            }

            return output;

Comment: @the.Doc cant apply indexing on cust like that

Comment: Yes sorry, it needs to be cast to IDictionary first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static List<dynamic> RecordFactoryNew(IEnumerable <Property> columns, DataRowCollection dr) {

    var output = List<dynamic>();

    for (int i = 0; i < dr.Count; i++) {
        IDictionary<string, Object> cust = new ExpandoObject();

        foreach(var col in columns) {
            SetDateTimeKindUtc(columns, dr[i][col.Name]);
            cust.Add(col.Name, dr[i][col.Name]);
        }

        output.Add(list);
    }

    return output;
}
```